# How to implement linked ListViews?

Tags: android, listview, drop-down-menu, spinner

I want to create a dropDown listview and to open a another one(dropDown) when an item is selected in the first one . I have read a lot about spinner,ListViews etc..nothing seems to be useful... thank you

Comment: Maybe this is useful to you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is a bad GUI pattern.
And you should manually change data for second list view (spiner) after choosing item from first

Answer (score 0):

Here my moto is to add the adapter to the `months drop down` when the user selects the `year` in the `year drop down` only.

so i call the `changemonths()` method when the user clicks on the year in the drop down.

so for every time when the user selects `year` months drop down will be `refresh`

```
 yearDropdown.setAdapter(Adapteryear);//=====> Here I am adding adapter to the year drop down.

 yearDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        selectedyear = parentView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        drpyear      = yearDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
        changemonths();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {

    }
});


 public void changemonths()
 {

  adaptermonth = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { 
            if(i<10)
                adaptermonth.add("0"+String.valueOf(i));
            else
                adaptermonth.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }


    monthDropdown.setAdapter(adaptermonth);
 }
```

This is my own application's code. if you need you can implement in this way. its not a solution. Its just a reference to your requirement

Good luck